# Run commands in text file in bash

Tags: bash

How can I run a command from a line inside a text file, one line of my text file looks like this

```
echo "RouterPing;`ping -c4 -w4 -q DeviceIP| tail -2 |awk '{print}' ORS=' '`;$(date)" >> somefile.txt &
```

I have a file that has thousands of lines that being generated by external program and want to execute every line in it. I need each line to be run exactly as if I am running it from bash shell

Answer (score 1):

You can just run:

```
bash file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below , but i would highly not recommend executing 1000 commands from a file ,

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read -r line
do
$line
   done < "$filename"
```

How to use 
./this_file_name.sh file_with_commands

Answer (score 1):

```
you$ bash somefile.txt
```

Just make sure your file is executable (`chmod 744 somefile.txt`)

Comment: Actually if you invoke bash like this the file does not need to be executable. Bash will just execute the file regardless of headers or file extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @ChristopherStobie.
Executable mode is only required if the file is invoked like `./somefile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

with dot ('.') (I removed the & because if the command runs in background it wont work)

```
echo "RouterPing;`ping -c4 -w4 -q DeviceIP| tail -2 |awk '{print}' ORS=' '`;$(date)" >> somefile.txt 

. somefile.txt
```